React margin prop affecting other components
When I apply margin to a component in my React application, it seems to unintentionally affect another component as well. For instance, when I add margin to Component B, Component A also appears to inherit this margin. I expect the margin to only be applied to the targeted component. Why might this be occurring?enter image description here
Component A stlyes:
<div className="bg-header-color text-white px-2 md:px-16 fixed z-10 w-full"></div>

Component B styles :
<div className='bg-green-600 w-full mt-20 h-[200px] text-white flex items-center justify-center space-x-7'></div>

I tried applying margin to Component B while Component A has a fixed position. However, both components still seem to share the same margin. I expected Component B to have its own margin without being affected by the fixed position of Component Aenter image description here
component A = Blue and component B=Green

Please show us the relevant code and (if applicable) style sheets

I put relevant code
